# why cout statement in Ubuntu not working as expected?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, terminal, command, cout

I tried to write this code in Ubuntu and run it from terminal
but the problem is the second "cout" statement prined before the first one.

```
for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
    cout << " the program will start within " << i << " seconds" << endl;
    cout << " be ready";
    sleep(1); //sleep 1 second before clearing the terminal
    system("clear");
}
```

**
the output:

be ready the program will start within 4 seconds
**

I wrote the corresponding code in windows and it runs successfully

Comment: `endl` flushes the output stream, forcing it to be displayed on the terminal. Add `<< flush;` after `" be ready"` to explicitly flush the output.

Comment: Alternatively, use '\n'. It's most of the time enough.

Comment: It's not really printed before the first one, but it's only written to the terminal after clearing the screen. If you remove the clearing, you will see "the program will start ...", and then there is a delay before you see "be ready the program will start ...".